# how to link urls at the back end using php on xampp server

Tags: php

Can I get idea about **linking of uniform source locator**(i.e i have to do online checking) at the  back end and my topic is **PLAGIARISM**.I tried a lot but can't make it happen.

[my project statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsYs5.jpg)

Comment: Show what you tried (show some code!). Define more precisely what you want to make happen.

Comment: no idea what your asking

Comment: could u help me @Louys Patrice Bessette to insert an image in a comment as i m new user

Comment: In a question, it is possible to insert an image. Not in a comment. Click on the "edit" link below your question and look for the "mountain icon", which is the 6th from the left.

Comment: Ok... Is that your homework assigment? Did you Google a little to find something ?

Comment: it is our  project .Yes,i did...We make site on it and it was checking grammar but not displaying links and i refer [link](https://www.plagiarismsoftware.net)

Answer (score -1):

To achieve it with the help of php here is the link

https://www.quora.com/Is-there-any-free-PHP-script-for-a-plagiarism-check

Comment: link only answers are discouraged